# Facebook status update URL

Tags: facebook, status

Does Facebook provide a URL the user can access that will take him to his profile page with the "What's on your mind" box auto completed with a value provided in the URL? I need something like "http://facebook.com?status=This is my new status message".

Comment: What do you need this for? What will you do with the URL?

Comment: No disrespect/offense intented. Why do people who will potentially answer the question sometimes first ask "why?"?

Comment: The user should have a button on my site that will take him to FB with a status about his actions/status on my site ("I did this, there...").

Comment: @j-t-s: in this case, I wanted to know if this was a programming question, or a FaceBook question, since he said nothing about programming.

Comment: It's clearly not a programming question, so it must be a FB question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FB.Connect.streamPublish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish), like so:

```
FB.Connect.streamPublish("I just visited dandu's website!");
```

Of course, this means creating an application and loading the Facebook Connect JS libraries in your website, check their docs for how to do that (setting up can be a daunting task). The advantage of doing so is that you don't need extended permissions. However, the user will be prompted and will have the choice of not updating their status through your app.

AFAIK, there's no simple URL to set a user's status (like [twitter has](http://twitter.com/?status=Hey+there)), just the "sharer.php", which doesn't take a status message.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for (something simple like twitter has), but it seems this is the best FB can offer right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you'll have to authenticate as described on the REST api documentation for status.set: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set

I couldn't find another option, and since they require you to authenticate for that method, it is reasonable to assume they'll require you to authenticate for any api that lets you update the status.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. I don't want to automatically post the message, I want the user to click on the "Share" button, I want the user to be able to review and edit the message before posting.

I found "/connect/prompt_feed.php" and "/sharer.php" but again not exactly what I want. I don't want a striped down mobile page and I don't necessary want to post a URL to share.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar. 
This seems to detail what you are looking for:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

Try This for Facebook status update URL:

```
      url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;

      json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.POST, url, "message=" + msg);
```